# Отмена события mousover

Tags: javascript, css

На странице имеется несколько ссылок, при клике вешается некий класс модификатор. Подскажите как отменить mousover на ссылку на которой висит этот самый класс.
 Т.е, если на ссылке висит класс - событие `:hover` на ней срабатывать не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, думаю суть будет ясна

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
.test:not(.clear):hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test clear"></div>
```

Реализация jquery

```js
$(function(){
 $('.test').on('mouseenter', function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('clear')){
       $(this).css('background','gray');
     }
 }).on('mouseleave', function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('clear')){
       $(this).css('background','none');
     }
 })
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test clear"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, суть понял с этим примером. Но раз уж речь о JS пошла было бы интересно посмотреть, как только изучающему язык вдвойне.

Comment: можно с jquery или на чистом?